# Excel Reporting linked to SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-designer, excel, office-integration, excel-web-access-webpart

I'm currently having some issues linking Excel to my online calendar (list) whenever I choose the web as a data source and I enter the URL of the calendar I get the option to only import the entire page (The yellow arrow box in top right corner)

[image: Image of error]

https://test1.sharepoint.com/sites/ITService/AppsManagement/RetailIntegration/Integration/Lists/Integration%20Team%20Calendar/calendar.aspx

First question...Should I be using the entire link or should be going up a level so to /Integration%20Team%20Calendar/

Secondly - When I choose to import the entire site i get another error which is:

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/53rX3.png): [image: Import error]
I'd be very happy if you could let me know a solution/about this issue

Thanks in advance

Comment: instead of the calendar.aspx, use the allevents or allitems.aspx, since it's a list of the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who may stumble across this - It's not possible Pre 2013

The link I followed to complete this is as follows:

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/excel_services__powerpivot_for_sharepoint_support_blog/2015/07/28/excel-services-consuming-a-sharepoint-list-using-the-listdata-svc/

Thanks anyway guys